# Calculate Load time for Dynamically Created Div Element and all Child Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to calculate load time of dynamically created div element with all child elements . I have one button, onclick of this button, am adding 100 images and listeners like click,mouseover,mouseleave.mousemove to the image element.

So I want to know how much time taken (like dom create and append timing, image load timing plus event listeners register timing) to the div, ready for the user interaction.

For that I have tried console.time("loadTime") and console.timeEnd("loadTime") which is executing before all the image is loading.

I am looking for same as window.load event for div element.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addImg").click(function(){
            $("#imgContainer").empty();
            console.time("loadTime");
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            $("#imgContainer").append(div);
            for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = "http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image"+i;
                img.alt = 'post';
                img.className = 'img-responsive';
                img.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    alert("EVent Clicked");
                });
                img.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
                    console.log("mouseover");
                });
                img.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
                    console.log("mouseleave");
                });
                img.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){
                    console.log("mousemove");
                });
                div.append(img);
             }
             console.timeEnd("loadTime");

        });
    });
```

I made same in jsfiddle also.

https://jsfiddle.net/aprakash290/31h2sbjz/2/

Comment: Aside from the performance testing, use a single delegated event for each event type instead of creating an event listener for every element. That'll save you quite a bit of time.

Comment: What purpose will knowing the load time serve? Sidenote: You can already speed up your code by using a documentFragment and only appending to the live DOM once or appending the div after the loop to the imgContainer. Changing the live DOM inside a loop is notorious for being one of the slowest things in the browser, so try to avoid it.

Comment: It's very odd to use `jQuery` for selecting (and modifying) an element - `$('#imgContainer')` and then use native dom methods to also append/add listeners. Use jQuery or not, but don't mix native DOM and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To know when all images have been loaded you can use the `load` event. When this event fires on an image increment a count. When this count matches the known number of images, you know they have all loaded and can call `console.timeEnd()`.

Try the below example, but note that it will be much quicker on the second call as the images will be cached. You will need to amend the URL or clear your cache to see the full load time again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addImg").click(function() {
    $("#imgContainer").empty();
    console.time("loadTime");
    
    var loadedCount = 0;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $("#imgContainer").append(div);
    
    for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image" + i;
      img.alt = 'post';
      img.className = 'img-responsive';
      img.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("EVent Clicked");
      });
      img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        console.log("mouseover");
      });
      img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        console.log("mouseleave");
      });
      img.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        console.log("mousemove");
      });
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        loadedCount++;
        if (loadedCount == 99) {
          console.timeEnd("loadTime");
        }
      });
      div.append(img);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addImg"> Append Image</button>
<h2>Image Test</h2>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

However it's worth noting that if performance is a major concern you should not be using jQuery at all.

Also, do not apply event handlers to the images individually. Use single delegated event handlers for each event type which are assigned to parent elements. Here's an example which does that:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#imgContainer');

document.querySelector('#addImg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.innerHTML = '';
  console.time("loadTime");

  var loadedCount = 0;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG')
      console.log("click");
  });
  div.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG')
      console.log("mouseover");
  });
  div.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG')
      console.log("mouseleave");
  });
  div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG')
      console.log("mousemove");
  });

  container.appendChild(div);
  var cacheBreaker = new Date().getTime();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image" + cacheBreaker + i;
    img.alt = 'post';
    img.className = 'img-responsive';
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      loadedCount++;
      if (loadedCount == 99) {
        console.timeEnd("loadTime");
      }
    });
    div.append(img);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addImg"> Append Image</button>
<h2>Image Test</h2>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Am using GWT project. In this I have more than 1000 widgets like textfield images and am adding to AbsolutePanel Container So I want to know how much time it takes to render and interact with user.

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue to what your question asked.